# How to select a field of a JSON object coming from the WHERE condition

Tags: sql, arrays, json, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I have this table

```
id  name   json
1   alex   {"type": "user", "items": [ {"name": "banana", "color": "yellow"}, {"name": "apple", "color": "red"} ] }
2   peter  {"type": "user", "items": [ {"name": "watermelon", "color": "green"}, {"name": "pepper", "color": "red"} ] }
3   john   {"type": "user", "items": [ {"name": "tomato", "color": "red"} ] }
4   carl   {"type": "user", "items": [ {"name": "orange", "color": "orange"}, {"name": "nut", "color": "brown"} ] }
```

Important, each json object can have different number of "items", but what I need is the "product name" of JUST the object that matched in the WHERE condition.

My desired output would be the two first columns and just the name of the item, WHERE the color is like %red%:

```
id name  fruit
1  alex  apple
2  peter pepper
3  john  tomato
```

```
select id, name, ***** (this is what I don't know) FROM table
where JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$.items[*].color") like  '%red%'
```

Comment: Is that JSON valid? I dont think so! Does'nt it have to be?? I think so!

Comment: This is not valid JSON. You should have square brackets for `"items"`, not curly brackets. `"items: [ {"name": "banana", "color": "yellow"}, ... ]`.

Comment: Imagine that JSON contains 2 fruits with red color in one JSON value - what output do you want to see in this case?

Comment: How did you create the JSON you inserted into your database? It looks like that code need to be fixed first

Comment: I'm SORRY !!! I created on the fly ... it's not valid, SORRY but it's just to get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `json_table()`, if you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
select t.id, t.name, x.name as fruit
from mytable t
cross join json_table(
    t.js,
    '$.items[*]' columns (name varchar(50) path '$.name', color varchar(50) path '$.color')
) x
where x.color = 'red'
```

This function is not implemented in MariaDB. We can unnest manually with the help of a numbers table:

```
select t.id, t.name, 
    json_unquote(json_extract(t.js, concat('$.items[', x.num, '].name'))) as fruit
from mytable t
inner join (select 0 as num union all select 1 union all select 2 ...) x(num)
    on x.num < json_length(t.js, '$.items')
where json_unquote(json_extract(t.js, concat('$.items[', x.num, '].color'))) = 'red'
```

Comment: I'm running MariaDb 10.5 ... but it does not work I think :-(

Comment: @FlamingMoe: ah ok... You originally tagged your question MySQL (there is a separate MariaDB tag), hence my answer. See my edit for a MariaDB-compatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_EXTRACT()` function along with `Recursive Common Table Expression` in order to generate rows dynamically such as

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS 
(
  SELECT 1 AS n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1
    FROM cte
   WHERE cte.n < (SELECT MAX(JSON_LENGTH(json)) FROM t )
)
SELECT id, name, 
       JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(json,CONCAT('$.items[',n-1,'].name'))) AS fruit
  FROM cte
  JOIN t
 WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(json,CONCAT('$.items[',n-1,'].color')) = "red"
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=421a8b7aba9780226b074d11ac6e4d57)</kbd>